# Is there any shortcut to add Flutter pub packages in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, dart

VSCode allows you to add packages using search tool from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages), is there any equivalent shortcut or a way to do the same in Android Studio or IntelliJ?

Comment: This plugin can help you out for the same: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite/

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana Thanks that worked, however it is bit slow, but I am happy to accept your answer if you can write it below.

Comment: posted it as a answer, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Plugin from the Marius Höfler.

I have been using it since long.

Here is a link to the same:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite

You can find this plugin using Android Studio by going

// For windows

> File => Settings => Plugins => Marketplace.

As you said it is bit slow but I find it better than copy pasting from [pub.dev](http://pub.dev)

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio to add packages from pub.dev just enter the package name and version name after it in **pubsec.yaml** file of Flutter then above click **Pub get**

For example to add packages
font_awesome_flutter from pub.dev you only need to enter font_awesome_flutter: ^ 8.8.1

```
dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter: <latest_version>
```

Example:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1 //add here
```

Then you also need to import the package into the file that needs to use the icons from the font_awesome_flutter package

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

Comment: Hi, I am sure you read the question before you posted this answer.